# R-Cran decision tree

Tags: r, decision-tree, cran

I am trying to use the tree Package in [R-cran](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tree/tree.pdf). I am loading my csv file as follows:

```
data <- read.csv("C:/data2.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ";",dec = ".")
```

The last column in the file **represents the Class** Is that correct?

My question is should the class be represents in the first or las column of the file thank you.

```
   V1        V2     V3    V4      V5           CLASS
'X0000002'  NULL    0   NULL    'BETA'          1
'Y0034195'  NULL    2   NULL    'INTERNAL'      1
'X0000001'  NULL    0   NULL    'BETA'          2
'X0000002'  NULL    0   NULL    'BETA'          2
'X0000002'  NULL    0   NULL    'BETA'          2
'Y0034195'  NULL    0   NULL    'INTERNAL'      2
```

---

**CORRECTION**
OK I Have 24 Descrptors V1...V24. V24 is the class. I used the Rpart library in R Cran

```
library(rpart)
data <- read.csv("C:/data2.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ";",dec = ".")
d1-> data[,1:24]
fit <- rpart(v24~ v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+V20+v21+v22+v23,data=d1)
```

### I am getting the following Error Cannot Find object 'V24'

**Example : Solution**

```
# Regression Tree Example
library(rpart)
data <- read.csv("C:/data2.csv", header = T,sep=";")
fit = rpart(linkId ~ .,method  = "anova",data  = data)

printcp(fit) # display the results 
plotcp(fit) # visualize cross-validation results 
summary(fit) # detailed summary of splits

# create additional plots 
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) # two plots on one page 
rsq.rpart(fit) # visualize cross-validation results     

# plot tree 
plot(fit, uniform=FALSE, 
     main="Regression Tree for Mileage ",compress = TRUE )
text(fit, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.8)

# create attractive postcript plot of tree 
post(fit, file = "c:/tree2.ps", 
     title = "Arbre de Regression ")
```

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter if you use a formula: CLASS ~ V1 + V2 + V3 +V4 + V5, it will pick the correct column for you.

Comment: ahhh I see that's why they had for example **"Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start"** Kyphosis the class and the Age Number and Start are the Attributes right?

Comment: And A Question @Fernando If I don't have the name of the attributes at the first Row Can i Ttype it like this ?

Tr <-tree(data, v6~v1+v2+v3+V4+v5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the help with `?formula`, you should get the basics easily.

You need the *names* in your data frame, otherwise R cannot understand the formula. Also, you  can use a shortcut to use **all** variables:

```
fit = rpart(CLASS ~ ., data = data)
```

Or

```
fit = rpart(data = data, formula = CLASS ~ .)
```

If you use a different order for the arguments, you should name them (there's no need to use the second way though).

Comment: Thank you yes @fernando I think that i have a problem with loading the data, that's the error message
**Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'v24' not found**

Comment: Yep, so i this case there's no **v24** column.

Comment: Ah yes I had a reading problem I solved it stupid me. I was using the bad separator. Thank you for your help